# I want to get the value of a TrackBar with VCL GUI

Tags: c++, user-interface, c++builder, vcl, trackbar

I want to get the value of this TrackBar `TrackBar2`:

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm2::Panel3Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    TrackBar2->Position = 20;
}
```

I use VCL GUI with C++ in RAD Studio.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. What prevents you from simply read the value of `TrackBar2->Position`?

Comment: exactly. i dont know how to do it

Comment: To where do you want to read the value? What do you want to do with it? What have you tried? How did it (that you tried), not meet your expectation?

Comment: What's wrong with reading the `Position` property? `int position = TrackBar2->Position;` (`position` is redundant).